# Rubyでlocal環境にinstallしたwebrickがrequireできない

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

## 概要

[【Docker超入門 #5】アプリを作成・実行しよう](https://youtu.be/ZxwHVaq7FJo?si=XMdHbM914ucmUPVZ)

この動画を参考にdockerでRubyのwebrickを動作させようといろいろやっています。
Dockerfileからimageを作って、containerを作成、実行しようとしたところでwebrickがloadできないとエラったので、とりあえずwebrickをbundler経由でinstallしました。この時、gemのソースはvendor/bundlerに落ちるように事前に設定しています。

けれども、やっぱりrequireのところでエラーが出ます。どうすればいいでしょうか

## src

### ruby

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'bundler/setup'
require 'webrick'


srv = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new({
                                DocumentRoot: './',
                                BindAddress: '0.0.0.0',
                                Port: 8000
                              })

srv.mount_proc '/' do |_req, res|
  res.body = 'Hello, world!'
end

trap('INT') { srv.shutdown }

srv.start
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.2

RUN mkdir /var/www
COPY server.rb /var/www

CMD [ "ruby", "/var/www/server.rb" ]
```

### Gemfile

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

# gem "rails"

gem 'webrick', '~> 1.8'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.60', require: false
end
```

```
$ docker container run [オプション類] 

<internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
        from /var/www/server.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

```
$ tree -aL 1
.
├── .ruby-lsp
├── Dockerfile
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── server.rb
└── vendor

2 directories, 4 files
```

環境は、ubuntu on wsl、Ruby3.2です。gemは全て最新です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

直接の原因は、Ruby のバージョンが 3.2 になっていることと、docker コンテナの中で gem がインストールできていないことです。

参考になさっている動画では Ruby 2.7 を利用していますが、質問者さんは Ruby 3.2 を利用されています（これ自体は良いことです）。webrick gem は Ruby 3.0 において [Ruby 本体に同梱されなくなり](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/)、各自でインストールする形になりました。

今回の構成では Gemfile はあるものの実行時に Bundler を使わずに `ruby` コマンド単体で利用しているので、システムにインストールされた gem のみを利用することになります。そこに webrick が存在しなければ今回のようにロード時にエラーが出ます。なお、仮にホスト側の環境で vendor ディレクトリに gem を入れるようにしていたとしても、Dockerfile で COPY していないため docker コンテナの中には存在していません。

今回は Gemfile までは作られているので、Docker コンテナの中で Bundler を利用するようにすればエラーを解消できます。私だったらこう書くかなというのを以下に示します。

ファイル構成

```sh
% tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
└── server.rb

1 directory, 4 files
```

server.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'webrick'

srv = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new({
  DocumentRoot: './',
  BindAddress: '0.0.0.0',
  Port: 8000,
})

srv.mount_proc '/' do |_req, res|
  res.body = 'Hello, world!'
end

trap('INT') { srv.shutdown }

srv.start
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.2

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock server.rb /var/www/
RUN bundle config deployment 'true' && \
    bundle install

CMD [ "bundle", "exec", "ruby", "/var/www/server.rb" ]
```